# Faster way to see if a vector is in the row space of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I was given a matrix, for example:

$$
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        3 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

And asked which of 5 vectors is in the row space of the matrix, I would usually:

1. Use elementary row operations to get the matrix into row echelon form to find a basis for the row space of the matrix.
2. Use the augmented matrix $[A|B]$, where $A$ is a basis for the row space and $B$ is one of the 5 vectors, with each of the 5 vectors, to see which vectors can be can be constructed as linear combinations of the basis vectors.
3. A consistent system indicates that the vector can be constructed by linear combinations of the basis vectors for the row space of $A$.

However, this could possibly require 5 computations, which is a a significant use of time under exam conditions. Is there a faster way to go about this?

Please note that I am interested in general, methodical methods. Not simply looking at the vectors and hoping that one is an obvious linear combination.

EDIT: I need mathematical concepts based on the theory of linear algebra. For instance, when using the (slow) method I have mentioned above, we are using matrix operations and the augmented matrix [A|b] to see if there are any linear combinations of the basis vectors of the row space that construct the vector b.

Comment: "ERO"? Don't use non-standard short writings or you won't get understood. Anyway, I think it may be faster to form a matrix with the already given three vectors and all the given 5 vectors, and begin reducing using only the first three rows as pivots. Only the rows where you get all zeros belong to the row space.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry. The ERO (elementary row operations) abbreviation was instinctual. Care to elaborate on your method as an answer? I don't think I've heard of it before and It could be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just form a $\;8\times5\;$ matrix with the one you already have and the given five vectors below the third row, and begin reducing by rows as told

Comment: What DonAntonio says! Also, if it is time-critical the designer of an exam is aware of that, and should take it into account. They may (will?) expet you to be able to take advantage of observations forced upon you while you reduce. For example, you will quickly see that the row space of your example matrix is 2-dimensional, so after row reduction the testing of any vector is very fast.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Indeed, if we row reduce the matrix in my example above, we get a row space of dimension 2. But how does this make it quicker to test vectors?

Comment: @DonAntonio Do you mean put all the row vectors + 5 vectors into a matrix as column vectors and then apply elementary row operations to the first 3 rows?

Comment: Here (starting from the right end to take advantage of the repeated coordinates) You first get a basis $(1,2,1,1,1)$ and $(1,-1,0,0,0)$. And then
the final basis $u=(3,0,1,1,1)$ and $v=(-1,1,0,0,0)$ with key coordinates at positions 5 and 2 respectively. If you want to test whether 
$x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ is in their span you can tell right away that the only possibility is $x=x_5u+x_2v$. Checking whether that is the case is fast.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I do not understand the idea you're trying to convey. What does 'key coordinates' mean?

Comment: The position of the first non-zero entry that is normalized to $1$. Except I wanted to be sneaky and use the last non-zero entry instead. Observe that row reduction automatically makes this coordinate equal to zero in the other basis vectors.